# Assign dynamically nested array of classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I need to be able to receive data from an external API and map it dynamically to classes. When the data is plain object, a simple `Object.assign` do the job, but when there's nested objects you need to call `Object.assign` to all nested objects.
The approach which I used was to create a recursive function, but I stumble in this case where there's a nested array of objects.

**Classes**

```js
class Organization {
  id = 'org1';
  admin = new User();
  users: User[] = [];
}
class User {
  id = 'user1';
  name = 'name';
  account = new Account();
  getFullName() {
    return `${this.name} surname`;
  }
}
class Account {
  id = 'account1';
  money = 10;
  calculate() {
    return 10 * 2;
  }
}
```

**Function to initialize a class**

```js
function create(instance: object, data: any) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(instance)) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      for (const element of data[key]) {
        // get the type of the element in array dynamically
        const newElement = new User();
        create(newElement, element)
        value.push(newElement);
      }
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      create(value, data[key]);
    }
    Object.assign(value, data);
  }
}

const orgWithError = Object.assign(new Organization(), { admin: { id: 'admin-external' }});
console.log(orgWithError.admin.getFullName()); // orgWithError.admin.getFullName is not a function

const org = new Organization();
const data = { id: 'org2', admin: { id: 'admin2' }, users: [ { id: 'user-inside' }]}
create(org, data);
// this case works because I manually initialize the user in the create function
// but I need this function to be generic to any class
console.log(org.users[0].getFullName()); // "name surname"
```

Initially I was trying to first scan the classes and map it and then do the assign, but the problem with the array of object would happen anyway I think.

Comment: I think we need to step back a bit.  What does your input look like?  `{ id: 'org2', admin: { id: 'admin2' }, users: [ { id: 'user-inside' }]}`?  And should your output be an Organization with an admin and an array containing one user, holding an Account and a name?  If so, what is meant to be generic, and how would you expect to configure things to describe the relationships?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your code, what you basically want to do is, given an object, determine, what class it is supposed to represent: `Organization`, `Account` or `User`.
So you need a way to distinguish between different kinds of objects in some way. One option may be to add a `type` field to the API response, but this will only work if you have access to the API code, which you apparently don't. Another option would be to check if an object has some fields that are unique to the class it represents, like `admin` for `Organization` or `account` for `User`. But it seems like your API response doesn't always contain all the fields that the class does, so this might also not work.

So why do you need this distinction in the first place? It seems like the only kind of array that your API may send is array of users, so you could just stick to what you have now, anyway there are no other arrays that may show up.

Also a solution that I find more logical is not to depend on `Object.assign` to just assign all properties somehow by itself, but to do it manually, maybe create a factory function, like I did in the code below. That approach gives you more control, also you can perform some validation in these factory methods, in case you will need it

```
class Organization {
  id = 'org1';
  admin = new User();
  users: User[] = [];

  static fromApiResponse(data: any) {
    const org = new Organization()

    if(data.id) org.id = data.id
    if(data.admin) org.admin = User.fromApiResponse(data.admin)
    if(data.users) {
      this.users = org.users.map(user => User.fromApiResponse(user))
    }
   
    return org
  }
}
class User {
  id = 'user1';
  name = 'name';
  account = new Account();
  getFullName() {
    return `${this.name} surname`;
  }

  static fromApiResponse(data: any) {
    const user = new User()
    
    if(data.id) user.id = data.id
    if(data.name) user.name = data.name
    if(data.account) 
      user.account = Account.fromApiResponse(data.account)

    return user
  }
}
class Account {
  id = 'account1';
  money = 10;
  calculate() {
    return 10 * 2;
  }

  static fromApiResponse(data: any) { 
    const acc = new Account()

    if(data.id) acc.id = data.id
    if(data.money) acc.money = data.money

    return acc
  }
}

const data = { id: 'org2', admin: { id: 'admin2' }, users: [ { id: 'user-inside' }]}
const organization = Organization.fromApiResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't conceive of a way to do this generically without any configuration.  But I *can* come up with a way to do this using a configuration object that looks like this:

```js
{
  org: { _ctor: Organization, admin: 'usr', users: '[usr]' },
  usr: { _ctor: User, account: 'acct' },
  acct: { _ctor: Account }
}
```

and a pointer to the root node, `'org'`.

The keys of this object are simple handles for your type/subtypes.  Each one is mapped to an object that has a `_ctor` property pointing to a constructor function, and a collection of other properties that are the names of members of your object and matching properties of your input.  Those then are references to other handles.  For an array, the handle is `[`surrounded by square brackets`]`.

Here's an implementation of this idea:

```js
const create = (root, config) => (data, {_ctor, ...keys} = config [root]) => 
  Object.assign (new _ctor (), Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (data) .map (
    ([k, v]) => 
      k in keys 
        ? [k, /^\[.*\]$/ .test (keys [k]) 
              ? v .map (o => create (keys [k] .slice (1, -1), config) (o)) 
              : create (keys [k], config) (v)
          ] 
        : [k, v]
  )))


class Organization {
    constructor () { this.id = 'org1'; this.admin = new User(); this.users = [] }
}
class User {
    constructor () { this.id = 'user1'; this.name = 'name'; this.account = new Account() }
    getFullName () { return `${this.name} surname`}
}
class Account {
    constructor () { this.id = 'account1'; this.money = 10 }
    calculate () { return 10 * 2 }
}

const createOrganization = create ('org', {
  org: { _ctor: Organization, admin: 'usr', users: '[usr]' },
  usr: { _ctor: User, account: 'acct' },
  acct: { _ctor: Account }
})

const orgWithoutError = createOrganization ({ admin: { id: 'admin-external' }});

console .log (orgWithoutError .admin .getFullName ()) // has the right properties


const data = { id: 'org2', admin: { id: 'admin2' }, users: [ { id: 'user-inside' }]}

const org = createOrganization (data)

console .log (org .users [0] .getFullName ())         // has the right properties

console .log ([
  org .constructor .name, 
  org .admin .constructor.name,                       // has the correct hierarchy
  org .users [0]. account. constructor .name
] .join (', '))

console .log (org)                                    // entire object is correct
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The main function, `create`, receives the name of the root node and such a configuration object.  It returns a function which takes a plain JS object and hydrates it into your Object structure.  Note that it doesn't require you to pre-construct the objects as does your attempt.  All the calling of constructors is done internally to the function.

I'm not much of a Typescript user, and I don't have a clue about how to type such a function, or whether TS is even capable of doing so.  (I think there's a reasonable chance that it is not.)

There are many ways that this might be expanded, if needed.  We might want to allow for property names that vary between your input structure and the object member name, or we might want to allow other collection types besides arrays.  If so, we probably would need a somewhat more sophisticated configuration structure, perhaps something like this:

```js
{
  org: { _ctor: Organization, admin: {type: 'usr'}, users: {type: Array, itemType: 'usr'} },
  usr: { _ctor: User, account: {type: 'acct', renameTo: 'clientAcct'} },
  acct: { _ctor: Account }
}
```

But that's for another day.

It's not clear whether this approach even comes close to meeting your needs, but it was an interesting problem to consider.